# UI changes not persisting in ASP.Net application

Tags: jquery, html, css, asp.net, .net

I have a `table` that's hidden by default. When clicking the search button, I'm using jQuery to remove the `d-none` class and show the table.

```
<input type="submit" value="Search" class="btn btn-default" id="searchName" />
<table id="resultsTable" class="table d-none">
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#searchName").click(function () {
      $("#resultsTable").removeClass("d-none");
  });
});
```

It works, but only for a brief moment then the table disappears again. I think that has to do with persistence but unsure how to progress.

Can anyone point me in the right direction please?

Comment: Do you refresh your page or part with a table?

Comment: When you click the submit button you are causing the parent `form` to send a request to the server to send the information contained within the form fields. From the behaviour you describe this causes the page to be reloaded, and hence any UI changes you made are lost. If you want to retain them you need to save the state of the page and re-apply that state when the page next loads. Alternatively you can avoid the page reloading by using AJAX to send the form data instead. Finally note that your `if` condition to check `hasClass()` is redundant.

Comment: @PiotrStapp I'm guessing the page is being refreshed which is the issue? How would I stop that?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Thanks, that makes sense. Any examples I can follow to make such changes?

Comment: use `event.preventDefault()` [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault)

Comment: @HastaTamang that will also stop the data being sent though.

Comment: @FullerPrime there's AJAX examples in the jQuery docs: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax, although you should note this is a sizable pattern shift, so you will also need to change the way data is returned to that request and the way you handle the response on the client side. As this is done on a case-by-case basis there's no real examples for that.

Comment: oh yep, may be change input type to button?

Comment: @HastaTamang no, again that will stop the submission entirely. You don't seem to be understanding the problem.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan oh jeez finally understood, i'm out of SO. Thanks lol

Answer (score 0):

When clicking a type="submit" button the default behavior is to send the form to the server and refresh the page, so the javascript runs, and right after, the page is hit with a refresh, and the browser recieves the server answer, which might be the page again.

I haven't used ASP.Net in a while but if that button doesn't need to send anything to the server, you can just remove the type="submit" and change it to type="button".

Answer (score 0):

On submit the page refresh thus the original view of the page is opened. To avoid this try using IsPostBack to false which is available in asp.net. this would not refresh the page but will do the work.
Other way to hide the page on load and using JQuery you can show the table or the div on button click once again with IsPostBack back to be false.